# escaped characters from GET compared to hard coded string

Tags: php

I have a form from which I want to send a string containing \r\n. After I receive the string in php file using $_GET[name] I print it and it shows the \r\n characters. When I define a string which has the \r\n characters and I print it it doesnt show those characters.
Another thing is comparing those strings:

```
if($input == "Hello \r\n Good \r\n Sir!")//$input = "Hello \r\n Good \r\n Sir!"
    echo "equal!";
else
    echo "not equal!";
```

It shows not equal.

I thing its connected to magic quotes, so I added

1. magic_quotes_gpc = Off
2. magic_quotes_runtime = Off
3. magic_quotes_sybase = Off

to `php.ini` and it doesnt help. I took the php.ini file from phpinfo

Any other ideas?

I found that magic_quotes was removed as of PHP 5.4.0 so its not that.

Edit: As @Steve has mentioned the input string from the user is interpreted literally - the \ is shown as ascii %5C for example. I am looking for a way to make the server interpret the \r to %D - carriage return?

Comment: How are you adding the new line chars into the form? Via return key in a text area, or via literally typing \r\n into an input

Comment: @Steve I am literally typing \r\n

Comment: @Steve I think I see the problem here.. it saves different values inside the string...

Comment: Ok thats your issue. http://codepad.viper-7.com/FY6tkw

Comment: as a quick solution iuf you must do it this way `$input = str_replace('\r\n', "\r\n", $input);`

Comment: @Steve Thank you, Isn't there any way to make the server interpret the \r\n typed from the user as "\r\n"?

Comment: No, its the users browser that decides how to encode the characters the user inputs.  You must have very unusual users, most people dont have any idea that the escape sequence `\r\n` (or just `\n` on nix systems) is equivilent to a newline anyway

Comment: @Steve HAHA! you are correct! I checked it in other browser and it behaved differently! Is there any source that specifies that the user browser can specify it? also feel free to add answer.

Comment: Probably there are sources you can google, but i'm just going off experience.

Comment: If you really are bored you can probably find something here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 not that it will change your situation much

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove \n and \r
$input = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $input));
// Replace multi spaces
$input = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $input);

if($input == "Hello Good Sir!")
    echo "equal!";
else
    echo "not equal!";
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I am not interested in programatically removing those slashes. I want the input to be used as normal string right when receiving it.

Comment: I think compare text like you are doing is not a good idea. Any space or new line and your test won't be good. And you really want to compare with string like "Hello \n\n\n\r good \r sir" ?! Hard to maintain a such code !

Comment: Its for test purposes. I dont want the comparison to be hard coded I want the input from form to be handled the same as the hard coded string.